# Haskell Turtle - getting Text output from inshellWithErr

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

What I tried:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let eitherSuccessOrErrorLine = inshellWithErr "stack build" empty
  stackBuildOutput <- strict $ case eitherSuccessOrErrorLine of
    Shell (Left line)  -> line
    Shell (Right line) -> line
  putStr stackBuildOutput
```

Error message:

```
src/Main.hs:34:12: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Turtle.Shell.FoldShell
                                      (Either Turtle.Line.Line Turtle.Line.Line) r0
                                    -> IO r0’
                  with actual type ‘Either (Shell Turtle.Line.Line) b0’
    • In the pattern: Left line
      In the pattern: Shell (Left line)
      In a case alternative: Shell (Left line) -> line
   |
34 |     Shell (Left line)  -> line
   |            ^^^^^^^^^

src/Main.hs:35:12: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Turtle.Shell.FoldShell
                                      (Either Turtle.Line.Line Turtle.Line.Line) r1
                                    -> IO r1’
                  with actual type ‘Either a0 (Shell Turtle.Line.Line)’
    • In the pattern: Right line
      In the pattern: Shell (Right line)
      In a case alternative: Shell (Right line) -> line
   |
35 |     Shell (Right line) -> line
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to create a function:

```hs
runStackBuild :: Shell ()
runStackBuild = do
  out <- inshellWithErr "stack build" empty
  liftIO $ putStrLn $ lineToText $ bifold out
```

and call it from `main :: IO ()`:

```hs
putStrLn "Starting `stack build`"
sh runStackBuild
putStrLn "Finished `stack build`"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're attempting to pattern match on the result of `runShellWithErr`. `runShellWithErr` does return a `Shell (Left Line) (Right Line)`, but `Shell` is defined thusly:

```
newtype Shell a = Shell { _foldShell:: forall r . FoldShell a r -> IO r }
```

Which is why your pattern is failing.

Instead of trying to pattern match on the result of `runShellWithErr`, it's cleaner to extract the line from the `Either` within the `Shell` monad. Like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let successOrErrorLine = do
        buildOutput <- inshellWithErr "stack build" empty
        return $ case buildOutput of 
            Left line -> line
            Right line -> line
    result <- strict successOrErrorLine
    putStr $ show result
```

Which can be done more succinctly as

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let successOrErrorLine = (either id id) <$> (inshellWithErr "stack build" empty)
    result <- strict successOrErrorLine
    putStr $ show result
```